# Pressure of a system of particles

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, molecular-dynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'll derive the pressure of a system of particles, which would be used in a MD simulation for example, according to Allen's *Computer Simulation of Liquids* and show where my issue is.

Consider a Hamiltonian system with $N$ interacting particles and generalized coordinates $q_k$. The virial theorem is:

$$ 
\langle q_k \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_k} \rangle = kT
$$

This implies that

$$ 
\frac{1}{3} \langle \sum_i \mathbf{r}_i \cdot \mathbf{f}_i^{tot} \rangle = NkT
$$

where $\mathbf{f}_i^{tot}$ is the total force including interparticle and external forces. So we can split this force into *internal* and *external* contributions, $\mathbf{f}_i^{tot} = \mathbf{f}_i^{ext} + \mathbf{f}_i^{int}$. The external part of the force defines the pressure on the system via

$$ 
\frac{1}{3} \langle \sum_i \mathbf{r}_i \cdot \mathbf{f}_i^{ext} \rangle = -PV
$$

- What is the reasoning behind this equation?
- Why does the sum of dot products between particle position vectors and external forces equal $-PV$?